# Cannot alter Form size/bounds at runtime (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Form which is owned by a UserControl (which in turn is heavily nested in other Forms/UserControls).  In order to resize the Form when the UserControl resizes I execute the following inside an override of the UserControl's OnLayout method:

`this.Form.Bounds = someValidRectangle;`

Now when I resize the application's window and this line executes the value of Bounds does not change.  I also tried setting the Height and Width explicitly to no avail.

On my Form, AutoScale = false, AutoSize = false, AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly, MinimumSize & MaximumSize = 0,0.

I've never come across an issue like this before.  What could prevent the size of my form from actually being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the heavy nesting was the key. I came across this article that describes the Windows limitation of resizing nesting controls: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/11/20/controls-won-t-get-resized-once-the-nesting-hierarchy-of-windows-exceeds-a-certain-depth-x64.aspx

Summary: the kernal stack blows out due to all the resize calls, preventing further resize messages from the OS.

Comment: Quite interesting. Never happened to me as well, so thumbs up for this link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you overrided the **SetBoundsCore** method of your control as well ? If not, try doing so.

EDIT: Read as well the respective msdn documentation that contains notes about overriding it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my case, WindowsState was affecting it. The code below worked for me:

```
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Size = bounds.Size;
        Bounds = bounds;
```